# Anybody know of a good explanation of each of the directories in root (/)?

Tags: linux, macos, unix

I want to know the purpose of each folder in the root directory of linux/mac, like /var, /etc, /usr, /opt, etc.  Can anybody shed some light?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about UNIX system conventions, and thus a better fit for UNIX.se. (where it's probably already a dupe)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know why you made that vote - I appreciate that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [File Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) (at least for Linux). See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/98751/50557) and the [Linux standard base](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb).